# Laravel error is not passed to view

Tags: laravel, error-handling, laravel-blade

I can't figure put why laravel blade doesn't catch my error validation and doesn't pass it to my view.
In detail

- I do have error snippet in my blade template
- below is my validation which works correctly

What I'm missing?

Thank you

This is json message I see instead of message in blade template

> {
>   message: "The given data was invalid.",
>   status_code: 500
>   }

This snippet I use to let user know about error

```
@if(count($errors))
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @if($errors->all())
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            @endif
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> @endif
```

And finally this is my correctly working validation

```
        $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers|max:255',
    ]);
```

EDIT:

This is the rout in web.php

```
Route::post('saveemail', 'SaveSubscriberEmailController@saveEmail');
```

And this is the method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\subscriber;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;


class SaveSubscriberEmailController extends Controller
{

    public function saveEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers|max:255',
        ]);



        $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();

        $subscriber = new subscriber();
        $subscriber->email = $request->email;
        $subscriber->uuid = $uuid->toString();
        $subscriber->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $subscriber->save();

        flash('Registration conformation email has been sent. Please check your mailbox. Thank you!')->success();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your route should be inside the web middleware or session wont work, this includes your $errors variable

Comment: added method and route definition. It's in the routes/web.php so it should be inside web middleware as well

Comment: `web.php` is automatically in the web middleware. You can check it by calling `php artisan routes:list`. You should see `web` next to your route in the Middleware column.

Comment: it is in the web route,confirmed with `php artisan routes:list`

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before and the way I was able to fix it was to wrap the routes with a middleware group that includes the middleware `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class`. It adds the session's errors to the view.

In your `Kernel.php` class's `protected $middlewareGroups` array it can look something like:

```
'web' => [
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    // other middleware
],
```

Then where you declare your routes you can do:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () { 
    Route::post('saveemail', 'SaveSubscriberEmailController@saveEmail'); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Route::post('saveemail', 'SaveSubscriberEmailController@saveEmail');`

Put this route into `web` middleware. you can do this like

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {

   Route::post('saveemail', 'SaveSubscriberEmailController@saveEmail');

});
```

Change your controller to this.

```
class SaveSubscriberEmailController extends Controller
{

public function saveEmail(Request $request)
{



    $validator = validate($request->all(),[
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:subscribers|max:255',
    ]);

   if($validator->fails()){
    return back()->withErrors($validator);
 }



    $uuid = Uuid::uuid4();

    $subscriber = new subscriber();
    $subscriber->email = $request->email;
    $subscriber->uuid = $uuid->toString();
    $subscriber->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $subscriber->save();

    flash('Registration conformation email has been sent. Please check your mailbox. Thank you!')->success();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: @Vojta you have to use `withErrors`, take a look at my answer I have updated this.

Comment: unfortunatelly no change. Your code is not executed as if validation fails rest of the method isn't executed.

Comment: @Vojta it has nothing to do with dingo API.

Answer (score 0):

Request validation only send error of 422 not 500 if you are getting this error it's because of something else and the formRequest error bag won't catch this error .